# How can I get my app to keep running and NOT wait for a DNS resolution error

Tags: ios, multithreading, cocoa-touch, dns, nsurlconnection

I have a program that calls a web service post to update information but in the case of a DNS resolution failure, the app just waits for about 30 seconds for the error to come back before it continues normal execution.

NOTE: If the web service post fails, the application can still run fine, so I don't want to wait for the response. Just post and move on, having the error come back whenever it does.

Below is the send method that comes back with error 410.

```
// Sends the request via HTTP.
-(void)send {

    // If we don't have a handler, create a default one
if(handler == nil) {
    handler = [[SoapHandler alloc] init];
}

// Make sure the network is available
if([SoapReachability connectedToNetwork] == NO) {
    NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"SoapRequest" code:400 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"The network is not available" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
    [self handleError: error];
}

// Make sure we can reach the host
if([SoapReachability hostAvailable:url.host] == NO) {
    NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"SoapRequest" code:410 userInfo:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject:@"The host is not available" forKey:NSLocalizedDescriptionKey]];
    [self handleError: error];
}

// Output the URL if logging is enabled
if(logging) {
    NSLog(@"Loading: %@", url.absoluteString);
}

// Create the request
NSMutableURLRequest* request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL: url];
if(soapAction != nil) {
    [request addValue: soapAction forHTTPHeaderField: @"SOAPAction"];
}
if(postData != nil) {
    [request setHTTPMethod: @"POST"];
    [request addValue: @"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField: @"Content-Type"];
    [request setHTTPBody: [postData dataUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    if(self.logging) {
        NSLog(@"%@", postData);
    }
}

// Create the connection
conn = [[NSURLConnection alloc] initWithRequest: request delegate: self];
if(conn) {
    receivedData = [[NSMutableData data] retain];
} else {
    // We will want to call the onerror method selector here...
    if(self.handler != nil) {
        NSError* error = [NSError errorWithDomain:@"SoapRequest" code:404 userInfo: [NSDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys: @"Could not create connection", NSLocalizedDescriptionKey,nil]];
        [self handleError: error];
        }
    }
}
```

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated!

Thanks in advance. :)

Comment: I don't understand your question. You seem to be currently executing your request asynchronously, so it already behaves like you want, 'post and move on, having the error come back whenever it does', doesn't it? Could you be more precise?

Comment: Is `SoapReachability` blocking the thread or something?

Comment: KPM....you are right on, I thought this should work like I want but it's not thus my question. Now I do use a try/catch/finally on the original call to the send, would that cause this?

Comment: So how do I tell if a method is asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: ‘How do I tell if a method is asynchronous or synchronous?’ -> Read the doc :) There is no other way to tell — except if the method name is explicit about that, which is not the case here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to add some returns. I believe that if host is unreachable, you don't want to proceed with the connection attempt.

Also, if one of your operations is blocking the thread, you might want to run your whole send method in a background queue.

Comment: Ok...so this is where I ended up. Drilling down to the command that is taking all this time is the following:

struct hostent *host = gethostbyname([theHost UTF8String]);

Why would that being stopping everything?

So you were right on the returns, I added those cause they should have been there but Carl nailed the start of the rabbit hole with SoapReachability which ended with the above line.

Any thoughts on this line? Also how do I tell if a method is asynchronous or synchronous?

Comment: If SoapReachability is blocking the thread, you might want to run your whole `send` method in a background queue.

Comment: KPM...thank you!!! You helped me first track down the issue and then gave me the key words "background queue" which after doing some reading fixed everything! I used [self performSelectorInBackground:@selector(processUploadInBackground) withObject:self]; and everything works smooth and if the upload fails, it fails whenever. Thanks again! It's tough starting out learning all this from scratch and people like you who are willing to lend advice really help get us past hurdles!

Comment: Glad I could help. Would appreciate an upvote in addition to the accept :) I will edit my answer to add the information about the background thread so that it can be useful to others as well.

Answer (score 0):

if use dipatch_queue thread will not block.My code as bellow.

```
    if(connectToHostQueue != NULL)
{
    dispatch_release(connectToHostQueue);
    dispatch_suspend(connectToHostQueue);
    connectToHostQueue = NULL;
}

connectToHostQueue = dispatch_queue_create("hostAvailable",NULL);
dispatch_async(connectToHostQueue, ^{
        isHostAvailable = [SoapReachability hostAvailable:url.host];

    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{

        // don't want to continue if process is canceled
        if(isCancel)
        {
            return;
        }

            // Connection process here..............
```

............................

```
             });
});
```